# How to remove duplicate words only from string with str.join() leaving numbers/digits intact?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, duplicates

I'm trying to figure out and put together a somewhat complicated syntax (for me) with .join function for hours already but just can't get it to work.

The task is to remove all duplicate words from a string obtained through scraping process but leave all duplicate numbers and digits intact.

Example Code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

examplestring = 'Your Brand22 For Awesome Product 1 Year 1 User Subscription Brand22'
print(' '.join(OrderedDict((w,w) for w in examplestring.split()).keys()))
>>> Your Brand22 For Awesome Product 1 Year User Subscription
```

Note that the above code works but removes the duplicated 1 (1 Year 1 User) too, which I need. I'm trying to leave the numbers intact by comparing it to isdigit() function as .split() goes through the string word by word but cannot figure it out what is the proper syntax for it.

```
result = ' '.join(OrderedDict((w,w) for w in examplestring.split()).keys() if w not isdigit())
result = ([' '.join(OrderedDict((w,w) for w in examplestring.split()).keys())] if w not isdigit())
result = ' '.join([(OrderedDict((w,w) for w in examplestring.split()).keys()] if w not isdigit()))
```

I tried many more different variations of the above one-liner code and might be even missing the if statement, but these brackets everywhere confuse me so I'm grateful if anyone can help me out.

Goal: Remove duplicate words but keep repeated digits/numbers inside the string

Comment: The scope of `w` is only inside the comprehension, but moving that also will not help you here.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same, just could not figure out what brackets or parentheses should I put before/after the code and where to use the if statement, too. By the way, first answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can Solve the problem by modifying the keys if the key is a number. Here I'm using enumerate to modify the key if key is numeric.

```
examplestring = 'Your Brand22 For Awesome Product 1 Year 1 User Subscription Brand22'

res = ' '.join(OrderedDict(((word + str(idx) if word.isnumeric() else word), word) for idx, word in enumerate(examplestring.split())).values())

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
Your Brand22 For Awesome Product 1 Year 1 User Subscription
```

Comment: Your code solved my problem, thank you very much! I would not be able to come up with such a long and complicated line of code that does just a little but important part of my script. Appreciate your quick response and knowledge! +

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
example_str = '''Your Brand22 For Awesome Product 1 Year 1 User Subscription Brand22'''

words_list = example_str.split()
numeric_flags_list = [all([char.isnumeric() for char in word]) for word in words_list]

unique_words = [] 

for word, numeric_flag in zip(words_list, numeric_flags_list):
    if numeric_flag: 
         unique_words.append(word)
    else:
        if word not in unique_words:
        unique_words.append(word)
        else:
            continue
```